# Como alinear un icono vectorial en css

Tags: html, css

```css
/* montserrat-100 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat Thin'), local('Montserrat-Thin'),
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-100.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-100.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

/* montserrat-200 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-200.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat ExtraLight'), local('Montserrat-ExtraLight'),
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-200.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-200.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-200.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-200.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-200.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

/* montserrat-300 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat Light'), local('Montserrat-Light'),
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-300.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-300.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

/* montserrat-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'),
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-regular.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

/* montserrat-500 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-500.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'),
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-500.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-500.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-500.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

/* montserrat-600 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-600.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Montserrat SemiBold'), local('Montserrat-SemiBold'),
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-600.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-600.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-600.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-600.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/montserrat-v12-latin-600.svg#Montserrat') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}


*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  color: rgb(40,40,40);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

section{
  padding: 70px 50px;
}

h4{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

h3{
  font-weight: 200;
}

h5{
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px;
}


aside{
  background-color: rgb(227, 233, 239);
  padding: 30px 0 50px 0;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

p{
  text-align: left;
}

small{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

footer{
background-color: rgb(244, 246, 249);
  padding: 100px 0 70px 0;
}

.menu{
  background-color: black;
  padding: 8px;
}

.menu img{
  width: 90px;
}

.menu ul{
  float: right;
}

.menu ul a{
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.menu ul a:hover{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
}



.hero{
  background: url('../materiales/imagenes/hero_background2.jpg') no-repeat bottom / cover fixed;
}

.hero h4{
  color: white;
}

.section2{
  background: url('../materiales/imagenes/cancan-background.jpg') no-repeat top / cover fixed;
}

.section2 h2, .section2 p{
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 0;
}


.imgCenter {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imageHero{
  width: 60%;
  padding: 30px 0 200px 0;
}

.bigLogo{
  width: 300px;
}

.imgFooter{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

 small a{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 30px;
  /*width: 100px;*/
  /*padding-bottom: 50px;*/
  color: grey;
}

.section1 li{
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.section1 a{
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
}

.section1 article, .section3 article {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.33% - 81px);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.section2 article{
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
}

.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}

section .icons::before{
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  /*Como centrarlo sin dar margen, queda feo*/
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.botonNegro{
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 14px auto;
}

.botonBlanco{
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Descripcion de nuestra pagina -->
  <meta name="description" content="Tu servicio para eventos, contamos con un equipo de azafatas con aplia experiencia para todo tipo de eventos">
  <title>Clock events | Ayuda para eventos</title>
  <!-- Favicones -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="materiales/imagenes/favicon-114.png" sizes="114x114">
  <!-- font icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font/flaticon.css">
  <!-- Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="menu">
      <a href="#"><img src="materiales/imagenes/logo-white.png" alt="logo"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a hreflang="en" href="en/">EN</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Equipo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Galería</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header class="hero">
      <h4>Personal. Proyeccion y servicios para eventos</h4>
      <figure>
        <img class="imgCenter imageHero" src="materiales/imagenes/big-logo.png" alt="Clock events logo">
      </figure>
    </header>
    <section class="section1">
      <h4 class="nuestrosServicios">Nuestros servicios</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="flaticon-woman icons"></i><h5>Azafatas</h5></li>
        <li><i class="flaticon-male-user icons"></i><h5>Animación</h5></li>
        <li><i class="flaticon-monitor icons"></i><h5>Fotógrafos</h5></li>
        <li><i class="flaticon-pencil icons"></i><h5>Creativos</h5></li>
        <li><i class="flaticon-monitor icons"></i><h5>Programadores</h5></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix">
      </div>
      <article>
        <header>
          <h3>    Clock Events cuenta con un equipo propio de azafatas con amplia experiencia en toda clase de eventos</h3>
        </header>
      </article>
      <article>
        <p>Mediante un minucioso proceso de selección, encontramos al profesional que mejor se ajusta a tus necesidades para ofrecer la mejor imagen de tu empresa.</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <p>Ponemos a tu disposición profesionales formados específicamente para protocolo, ferias, congresos, entregas de premios, transfers e imagen, entre otros.</p>
        <a class="" href="#">Más informacion sobre azafatas</a>
      </article>
      <div class="clearfix">

      </div>
    </section>
    <aside class="aside1">
      <h4>Apuntate a nuestro newsletter</h4>
      <p><a class="botonNegro" href="#" title="suscríbete">Suscríbete</a></p>
      <small>Olvida el spam. Nosotros tambien lo detestamos</small>
    </aside>
    <section class="section2">
      <article>
        <header>
          <h2>¿Buscas soluciones para diferenciar tu evento?</h2>
          <p>Desde un show de Can-can al más puro estilo Far West hasta una noche de risa y terror en un caserón maldito. Lo tenemos.</p>
          <p><a class="botonBlanco" href="#">Contáctanos</a></p>

        </header>
      </article>
      <article>
        <figure>
          <img class="imgCenter bigLogo" src="materiales/imagenes/logo-detalle.png" alt="logo reloj">
        </figure>
      </article>
      <div class="clearfix">
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section3">
      <h4>Nuestros valores</h4>
      <div class="superior">
        <article>
          <i class="flaticon-flag icons"></i>
          <h5>Siempre estamos ahi</h5>
          <p>Cada persona es un mundo, y cada evento es diferente. No concebimos una atenciÛn que no sea personalizada, cercana, profesional y cálida.</p>
        </article>
        <article>
          <i class="flaticon-megaphone icons"></i>
          <h5>Somos creativos</h5>
          <p>La originalidad en la planificación y ejecución de nuestros proyectos nos permite plasmar en cada uno de ellos nuestro sello personal: la diferenciación.
          </p>
        </article>
        <article>
          <i class="flaticon-like icons"></i>
          <h5>Tenemos pasión</h5>
          <p>Y la plasmamos en cada uno de los proyectos. Y la contagiamos. Tenemos el privilegio de amar lo que hacemos, y lo hacemos con el corazón.
          </p>
        </article>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="inferior">
        <article>
          <i class="flaticon-wallet-with-card-sticking-out icons"></i>
          <h5>Cuidamos tu inversión</h5>
          <p>Somos conscientes del valor que tiene una inversión en nuestro trabajo, y nuestro objetivo es tu satisfacción con la misma. Vamos más allá de tus expectativas.</p>
        </article>
        <article>
          <i class="flaticon-line-chart icons"></i>
          <h5>Somos equipo</h5>
          <p>Gracias a que disponemos de unos recursos humanos seleccionados y coordinados especÌficamente para ti, podemos garantizar la calidad y calidez de nuestros servicios. Sabemos con quién trabajamos.
          </p>
        </article>
        <article>
          <i class="flaticon-hourglass icons"></i>
          <h5>Lo coordinamos</h5>
          <p>La coordinación activa y personal de cualquiera de nuestros servicios está incluida en los mismos. Estaremos allí, en tu evento, contigo. Nosotros nos ocupamos.
          </p>
        </article>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <img class="imgCenter imgFooter" src="materiales/imagenes/logo-footer.png" alt="logo_footer">
    <small><a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> Clock events 2015 | </a><a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> Aviso legal</a><a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> Cookies</a></small>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Hola buenas no se como centrar este icono vectorial, se comporta como texto pero es inline-block ya que no puedo darle margen arriba y abajo, quiero saber como centrar el icono junto al texto de abajo... se ve que me da un margen por defecto cuando lo pongo en block para cubrir el espacio restante, no se como arreglar esto, no queda alineado alguna sugerencia? 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos por favor el HTML y CSS que estás utilizando hasta el momento? Es muy difícil adivinar la estructura de tu proyecto si no nos proporcionas un ejemplo en el que lo podamos reproducir.

Comment: haha perdona iba a hacerlo aho lo subo =)

Comment: igual no puedo añadir todas mis carpetas con los iconos asique no saldran, sabes como añadir una carpeta con varios archivos?

Comment: La verdad es que desconozco como se pueden introducir archivos... Menciono a una persona del foro que casi seguro te puede ayudar, a ver si el sabe de alguna forma @Mariano

Comment: Podrias tratar un un `display: flex;` y usas la propiedad `align-content: center;`

Comment: como es flex? Acabo de emepezar a estudiar y aun no la he visto

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas cómo crear un [mcve] en el centro de ayuda. Para ver un problema de alineación no hace falta que copies toda la página o todo el CSS, sólo la sección que falla en particular y los estilos relacionados. Al hacer el [mcve], será más fácil ver el problema (ahora mismo no se ve porque faltan imágenes/elementos) y que te puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

En el div padre como ya te han comentado..

```
.padre {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Los elementos que estén dentro del div. estarán puestos uno debajo de otro y alineados al centro del div padre

Creo que es la solución más eficiente